# set the request paramaeter in jsf2.0 managed bean

Tags: jsf-2

i am using JSF2.0 and i want to set the request parameter values in Managed bean class and want to get in Second managed bean class. Then how can i do that please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use "view parameters" (f:viewParam).

You declare these on your Facelet for each request parameter that you wish to receive, and bind those to properties in your backing bean. You can attach converters and validators to them if you wish.

Alternatively, you can access the raw parameter map via the ExternalContext, which you can obtain from FacesContext.